# Ejabberd MucSub: When a member sends a presence unavailable, the service does not respond

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I'm working on persistent group conversations with Ejabberd 19.09 and mucsub.

When a member of a group sends a presence unavailable, sometimes the server does not respond at all. 
If we repeat the same test after sending a presence available just before the presence unavailable, the server responds.
In any case, apparently, we have no changes in the room occupancy.

Is this an expected behavior?

### First test:

**Steps to reproduce first test:**

1. admin `test1` creates a room `roomX` (members-only)

```xml
    <!-- [CREATE ROOM] | test1 -->
    <iq from='test1@x.com' to='roomX@conference.x.com' type='set' id='1111111'>
      <subscribe xmlns='urn:xmpp:mucsub:0' nick='test1'>
        <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:affiliations' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subject' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subscribers' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:presence' />
      </subscribe>
    </iq>
```

2. admin `test1` invites and subscribes the user `test2`

```xml
<!-- [INVITE test2] | test1 -->
<message from='test1@x.com' id='33333' to='roomX@conference.x.com'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
    <invite to='test2@x.com'><reason>REASON</reason></invite>
  </x>
</message>
<!-- [SUBSCRIBE test2 TO ROOM] | test1 -->
<iq from='test1@x.com' to='roomX@conference.x.com' type='set' id='222222'>
  <subscribe xmlns='urn:xmpp:mucsub:0' jid='test2@x.com' nick='test2'>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:presence' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subject' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subscribers' /><event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:presence' />
  </subscribe>
</iq>
```

3. the invitation is automatically accepted, user `test2` is now a room member, he can send messages and he is subscribed to all events
4. member `test2` wants to abandon the room, and sends a presence type=unavailable

```xml
<!-- [test2 leaves the room] | test2 -->
<presence to='roomX@conference.x.com/test2' from='test2@x.com' type='unavailable'>
  <status>leave</status>
</presence>
```

**Results:**

- service does not respond to member
- no changes to the room occupancy: member’s affiliation is still
  “member”, role is still “member”, subscription is still active

### Second test:

**Steps to reproduce second test:**

1. admin `test1` creates a room `roomX` (members-only)
2. admin `test1` invites and subscribes the user `test2`
3. the invitation is automatically accepted, user `test2` is now a room member, he can send messages and he is subscribed to all events
4. member `test2` sends a presence type=available (in theory this is redundant, but it's made on purpose as part of this test)

```xml
<!-- [test2 JOINS THE ROOM] | test2 -->
<presence from='test2@x.com' id='n13mt3l' to='room@conference.x.com/test2'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
</presence>
```

5. member `test2` wants to abandon the room, and sends a presence type=unavailable

**Results**

- service responds to member
- no changes to the room occupancy: member’s affiliation is still
  “member”, role is still “member”, subscription is still active

Answer (score 0):

> First test: Steps:
>   admin invites a member member

I guess using https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#invite-mediated

> sends a presence unavailable

Why that? It should be a message, not a presence:

> The invitee MAY choose to formally decline (as opposed to ignore) the
>   invitation; and this is something that the sender might want to be
>   informed about. In order to decline the invitation, the invitee MUST
>   send a **message** of the following form to the  itself:

Comment: The goal of this test is not to decline the invitation (which works fine), but to leave the group after being a member for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the first step which is :

```
<presence to='test2-157@conference.x.com/test1'  id='s6MLD-390'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'></x></presence>
```

Comment: In the "First test" i don't send the presence, but in mucsub join is automatic.
In the "Second Test" i send what you indicated, check the code block beginning with: <!-- [test2 JOINS THE ROOM] | test2 -->